# Mouse settings on RHEL5

Tags: rhel-5, administration, redhat-enterprise-linux

How to change the mouse settings to default on RHEL5 .i have a problem using mouse with vim.it acts like a single click select.Please advise..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not unusual in the *nix world to copy to the X11 primary buffer only by highlighting the text to be copied, with the middle button subsequently used to paste the copied text. This is normal behavior and *may* be configured on an app-by-app basis (e.g. Firefox's `middlemouse.paste` and `middlemouse.contentLoadURL` configuration options), but there is no global way to easily override this.

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/faq

What kind of questions should I not ask here?
[...]
General computer software or hardware troubleshooting, ask on  Super User.